# Compare multiple images based on pixel values

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Hi I am trying to compare a set of images where I want to produce a final image with maximum pixels from each individual image. Say I have 3 images (converted to 10x10 matrix) in which I know the pixel values of each block> Now I want to compare these values block by block and produce a final separate image with maximum block values from each image.

To do so I have changed the image dimensions(250x250) such that each block is a square of 25x25

I even tried comparing two images and taking the maximum pixels from both the images and displaying them

```
image = cv2.resize(im,(250,250))
hs,ws,c= image.shape
print(hs, ws,c)
hs = round(h/10)
ws = round(w/10)
resized = cv2.resize(image, (ws,hs), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow("Resized image", resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print(list(resized))
```

```
#comparing two images
data = np.maximum.reduce([resized,resized1])
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

So these are two images and the tiled image is the result of the block #comparing two images. Now using these two images I want to produce a final image similar to the original photos not the tiled version but the final photo should have pixels from both original photos(maximum from each). I hope it clears the question

Comment: Sorry, but I do not follow your question. Please elaborate and show a diagram or image.

Comment: @fmw42 I have a set of images(say 6), divided it into 10x10 blocks(each image). I did edge detection for all. Now from these six images I want to produce a final image such that the final image has pixel values which are a maximum from all these individual images. Think of each image as a layer and the final image has to has the pixel from the maximum block of 6 images. Did I make sense?

Comment: Do a resize using the AREA interpolation so that you resize your image such that each pixel in the smaller image represents 10x10 region in the larger image. Do that for each of your size images. Then get the maximum, pixel by pixel between each of the size reduced images. See my post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178208/grid-on-image-to-compute-the-average-color/58179173#58179173. Do that to each image. Then get the max of all 6 reduced images. If I have misunderstood, then try explaining again or provide a diagram

Comment: @fmw42 I have updated the question. Hope it gives some clarity

Answer (score 4):

For better visualization purposes, I skip the whole resizing part [you got earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58179173/11089932), and stick to resized `(250 x 250)` images.

My approach is the following: Store all your resized images in some NumPy array with dimensions `(width x height x numberOfChannels x numberOfImages)`, and then use NumPy's [`max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html) along `axis=3`, such that you get a final image `(width x height x numberOfChannels)` with maximum BGR values (or grayscale, if desired) over all images.

Here's some exemplary code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up empty images array
width, height, nChannels, nImages = (250, 250, 3, 3)
images = np.zeros((width, height, nChannels, nImages), np.uint8)

# Read and resize exemplary input images
images[:, :, :, 0] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('WeQow.png'), (width, height))
images[:, :, :, 1] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('gIHOd.png'), (width, height))
images[:, :, :, 2] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('lAdfO.jpg'), (width, height))

# Generate maximum image along last axis, i.e. the images.
# For each BGR value you get the maximum over all images.
image = images.max(axis=3)

# Show images
cv2.imshow('image0', images[:, :, :, 0])
cv2.imshow('image1', images[:, :, :, 1])
cv2.imshow('image2', images[:, :, :, 2])
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

These are the three input images:

[image: Input 1]

[image: Input 2]

[image: Input 3]

The final output image then looks like this:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nicely explained:-)

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks for the effort. I tried it using the original images and I was expecting that it will produce a clearer images as it would gather the maximum pixel value from a region but the result was not as I expected. Any suggestion on it?

Comment: @RockyJohanson What do you mean by "clearer image(s)"? The fly in your images for example won't get any "sharper" by using the maximum values from both images. What do you ACTUALLY want to achieve? Maybe using maximum values is wrong for your original problem, and the solution is something totally different!? You can again edit your question, but please be sure to not invalidate already given answers. If the topic/problem/question is too different, better ask a new question altogether.

Comment: @HansHirse okay I'll post a new question with complete description of the problem. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `block_reduce` function with block size `(no_of_images, channels, block_height, block_width)`.

```
skimage.measure.block_reduce(np.asarray([image1, image2, image3,...]), (no_of_images, channels, 1, 1), np.max)
```

If your input images are in RGB scale and you want per-channel max value (output also RGB image) among images just replace `channels value with 1` or if you want max value across channels among the images then use `3 as channels value` that will generate a gray scale image.